# Storing NSArray or NSDictionary in keychainWrapper in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

[keychainWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) provides the mechanism for storing a `NSString` (like passwords).

Can I also store `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` in `keychainWrapper`?

Comment: Where is key chain wrapper ?? gives its link in your question so that we don't have to search google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, and if you have custom objects stored in the array of dictionary, make sure that class implements the `NSCoding` protocol.

```
NSData * encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

You can then convert NSData to NSString using base64 encoding http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

for unarchiving it's just going backwards,use get `NSData` from the base64 `NSString` and use the unarchiver

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thank You.....@overboming ....But its not working....i'm getting the encoded sting as null...see the code in link....    [link](http://ashokios.blogspot.in/2013/02/storing-nsarray-or-nsdictionary-in.html)

Comment: @AshokKumarIOS Hi I have edited my answer accordingly, you should use base64 for 1 to 1 NSData and NSString translation. Also print out the NSData you got from the array and make sure it's not nil.